# ReferenceError: ArticleService is not defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I can't solve this for days, checked many other posts, please help.
Using example from this page:
http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/

**I'm using**

- Ionic
- Cordova
- PouchDB
- AngularJS

**My environment**

- Cordova CLI: 5.3.1
- Ionic Version: 1.1.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.5
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.9
- OS: Mac OS X Mavericks
- Node Version: v0.12.7

**controllers.js**

```js
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

 .controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
  var vm = this;

  // Initialize the database.
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    ArticleService.initDB();

    // Get all articles records from the database.
    ArticleService.getAllArticles().then(function(articles) {
      vm.articles = articles;
    });
  });
  
/*
  // Initialize the modal view.
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/playlists.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
*/
  
  vm.showAddArticleModal = function() {
    $scope.article = {};
  };

  vm.showEditArticleModal = function(article) {
    $scope.article = article;
  };

  $scope.saveArticle = function() {
      ArticleService.addArticle($scope.article);    
  };

  return vm;
})
```

**Playlists.html**

```html
<ion-view view-title="List">
  <ion-content>        
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-controller="OverviewCtrl as vm" ng-repeat="a in vm.articles" ng-click="vm.showEditArticleModal(a)">
        <div style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto">{{ a.image }}</div>
        <div style="float: center">{{ a.descr }}</div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

### services.js

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('ArticleService', ['$q', function($q) {
 
  var _db;    
  var _articles;

  return {
    initDB: initDB,

    getAllArticles: getAllArticles,
    addArticle: addArticle,
    
    ...
  };

  function initDB() {
    // Creates the database or opens if it already exists
    _db = new PouchDB('articles', {adapter: 'websql'});
  };

  function addArticle(article) {
    return $q.when(_db.post(article));
  };

  ...

}])
```

**menu.html**

```html
...

<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
  List
</ion-item>

...
```

**apps.js**

```js
.state('app.playlists', {
  url: '/playlists',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
      controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

camera.html

```html
 <ion-modal-view>
   ...
   
   <div class="padding">
      <button ng-controller="OverviewCtrl" ng-click="saveArticle()" class="button button-block button-positive activated">Spara</button>
    </div>
   
   ... 
</ion-modal-view>
```

I created an ArticleService to save the data from camera.html. The problem is already at build, ArticleService cannot be referenced in controllers.

Comment: why ArticleService  is not listed as a dependency for OverviewCtrl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. There were several issues in my code. Mainly in Services.js . Changed the function header for ArticleService to start with.

.factory('ArticleService', ['$q', ArticleService]);
function ArticleService($q) {

Also changed the function header for OverviewCtrl in Controller.js

.controller('OverviewCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$ionicPlatform', 'ArticleService', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPlatform, ArticleService ) {

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are using `ArticleService` in `OverviewCtrl`, but you are not injecting it to controller function. To fix it change

```
.controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
```

to

```
.controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, ArticleService) {
```

Comment: I have tried that :) Doing that will give me: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ArticleServiceProvider <- ArticleService <- OverviewCtrl

Comment: Have you included the services.js via the script tag in index.html?

Comment: <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>